# Hide Material mat-tab-body-wrapper specific to a component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material's tab component where I need to have multiple tabs and hide content of all the tabs. I tried modifying it using the following CSS:

.mat-tab-body-wrapper {
  display: none
}

This works for me, but with this, it also hides the content of other tabs in rest all other components and not specific to my component (applied globally though it should be private to component). I also tried setting viewEncapsulation to Native which disturbs the css used by other UI library. Is there a way to add an id attribute to mat-tab-body-wrapper so I catch particular component in style. I don't want to go jQuery way. Also, my tabs uses *ngFor to loop tab list and not individual tab in my template.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the scope of the class that hides tabs by applying a class to the main mat-tab component:

```
<mat-tab-group class="hides-tabs">
    ...
</mat-tab-group>

mat-tab-group.hides-tabs .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
    display: none
}
```

Or if your tabs are inside a custom component, you can use the component's selector as part of the CSS selector:

```
<my-component class="hides-tabs">
    <!-- component template includes mat-tab-group -->
    ... 
</my-component>

my-component.hides-tabs .mat-tab-body-wrapper {
    display: none
}
```